# How to change the colour of the lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data matrix called `mymat`. Below is the `code` I have used to plot the graph for the samples (`key.related.sheet`). What I need now is to change the colour of the lines that fall within the IBS range of 0.8-1.5 into blue, 0.4-0.6 in red and 0.1- (-0.1) in yellow and anything below -0.1 in green. How can we do this?

code

```
      library(data.table)
      library(ggplot2)
      library(dplyr)
      cpp <- melt(as.data.table(mymat), measure =  patterns("^IBS", "^Num_Good"), 
         value.name = c("IBS", "Num_Good")) %>%
      .[, c("IBS", "Num_Good") := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = IBS:Num_Good]
      ggplot(cpp, aes(x = Num_Good, y = IBS, col = key.related.sheet)) + 
      geom_line() + 
      #geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5)+
      geom_hline(yintercept = 1.0)+
      scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE)
```

data

```
mymat<- structure(c("AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0010", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0022", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0063", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0079", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0087", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0105", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0108", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0112", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0118", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0161", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0509", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0512", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0513", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0522", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0523", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-03-0094", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-03-0114", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-03-0122", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-03-0132", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-03-0138", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-05-0009", "1.12", "-0.00346", "0.0132", "0.0238", 
"0.00404", "-0.0201", "-0.00653", "-0.00466", "-0.00942", "-0.00484", 
"-0.0085", "-0.00231", "-0.03", "-0.0235", "-0.00412", "-0.0025", 
"-0.0111", "0.000753", "-0.0231", "-0.0205", "-0.0121", "67289", 
"52782", "51066", "46950", "47943", "51516", "59956", "57771", 
"52397", "58087", "54291", "33791", "24889", "65773", "65777", 
"51710", "55043", "50168", "64144", "64580", "57970", "1.13", 
"0.500283", "0.0108", "0.0227", "0.400507", "-0.0219", "-0.00914", 
"0.800371", "-0.0147", "-0.00372", "-0.00817", "-0.00983", "-0.0248", 
"-0.0205", "-0.012", "-0.0127", "-0.0107", "0.0106", "-0.026", 
"-0.023", "-0.900788", "53519", "42192", "40667", "37442", "38262", 
"40952", "47671", "45966", "41675", "46191", "43512", "27316", 
"20038", "52297", "52304", "41075", "43963", "39989", "51040", 
"51390", "46087", "1.12", "-0.00143", "0.00778", "0.0119", "0.00842", 
"-0.0237", "-0.0168", "0.00345", "-0.0112", "0.00414", "-0.00337", 
"-0.0097", "-0.0322", "-0.0275", "-0.0173", "-0.017", "-0.0081", 
"0.0256", "-0.0327", "-0.00254", "-0.0166", "26864", "21262", 
"20553", "18909", "19335", "20543", "23915", "23002", "20917", 
"23130", "22233", "14524", "10685", "26261", "26244", "20542", 
"22356", "20132", "25647", "25777", "23045", "1.15", "0.00715", 
"-0.00543", "0.0192", "0.0254", "-0.00775", "-0.00167", "0.00523", 
"-0.027", "0.0125", "0.00182", "-0.0262", "-0.0526", "-0.0178", 
"-0.0413", "-0.00793", "-0.00371", "0.0287", "-0.0141", "-0.00325", 
"-0.0199", "13923", "10935", "10434", "9755", "9929", "10669", 
"12505", "11958", "10818", "12048", "11064", "6635", "4757", 
"13599", "13612", "10740", "11252", "10394", "13261", "13371", 
"12042", "1.14", "-0.0122", "0.0103", "0.0189", "0.04", "0.0084", 
"0.0227", "-0.0101", "-0.0328", "-0.0134", "-0.00669", "-0.0421", 
"-0.0442", "-0.00531", "-0.044", "0.0526", "-0.00056", "0.0221", 
"0.0182", "0.0259", "-0.0362", "7240", "5750", "5535", "5151", 
"5202", "5567", "6525", "6231", "5618", "6291", "5892", "3645", 
"2674", "7084", "7084", "5567", "5962", "5481", "6925", "7004", 
"6279", "1.18", "0.0143", "-0.0763", "-0.00882", "0.0526", "-0.0195", 
"-0.0531", "-0.00064", "-0.00616", "-0.00746", "0.0173", "-0.0795", 
"0.0041", "0.018", "-0.0522", "0.0767", "0.0476", "0.000252", 
"0.0456", "0.0377", "-0.0391", "3527", "2766", "2691", "2487", 
"2461", "2672", "3135", "3010", "2680", "3056", "2846", "1707", 
"1265", "3444", "3444", "2682", "2886", "2638", "3366", "3402", 
"2982"), .Dim = c(21L, 13L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"), c("key.related.sheet", "IBS_from:1305328SNPS", 
"Num_Good_SNPs_A:1305328SNPS", "IBS_from:1030725SNPS", "Num_Good_SNPs_A:1030725SNPS", 
"IBS_from:514953SNPS", "Num_Good_SNPs_A:514953SNPS", "IBS_from:257361SNPS", 
"Num_Good_SNPs_A:257361SNPS", "IBS_from:128603SNPS", "Num_Good_SNPs_A:128603SNPS", 
"IBS_from:64000SNPS", "Num_Good_SNPs_A:64000SNPS")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the color of only sections of the line then you can add in something like this:

```
cpp$cutoff = cut(cpp$IBS, 
    breaks = c(-Inf, -0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.5),
    labels = c("GREEN", "YELLOW", "GREY", "RED", "BLACK", "BLUE"))
```

and then plot like this:

```
ggplot(cpp, aes(x = Num_Good, y = IBS, group = key.related.sheet, color = cutoff)) + 
    geom_line() + geom_point()+
    #geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5)+
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1.0)+
    scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE)
```

To make the entire lines the same color it depends on what color you which to adopt and the rules around that.

But you would probably group and summarise the data for that.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: I don't want to show the dots where the line diverge. What do I need to do for that?

Comment: just remove `+ geom_point()`, i added that in to check some things :)